# relative schema reference to openshift tls service

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

Exposed https soap service using openshift router TLS edge termination, but the xsd schema it is still taking as http reference.
examples: Service url https://example.net/test?wsdl
          but when accessing above wsdl on browser, it is generating xsd schema reference as

Please let me know how we can refer the schema in relative way.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in following [PR](https://github.com/openshift/origin/pull/4705/files), openshift haproxy should correctly add `X-Forwarded-Proto` header with `http` or `https` value. Your software should either use relative links if possible, if not, you can use the value of this header to check if your app was exposed by external load balancer as http or https and provide url's apropriately.